When I print the selection after html2pdf, I want to write the page number in footer for each page
async function generateAndUploadPDF() {
    const tableContent = document.getElementById('tableContent');
    const opt = {
        margin: [5, 10, 5, 10], // Margin in centimeters
        filename: 'table.pdf',
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1.0 },
        html2canvas: {
            useCORS: true,
            scrollY: 0,
            scale: 3, // Adjust scale as needed to fit content within A4
            letterRendering: true,
            dpi: 1000,
            // width: tableContent.offsetWidth,
            allowTaint: false
        },
        jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' },
        // pagebreak: { avoid: 'thead, tbody, tr' },

        // Add page numbers
        callback: function (pdf) {
            const totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
            for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
                pdf.setPage(i);
                pdf.setFontSize(10);
                pdf.text('Page ' + i + ' of ' + totalPages, pdf.internal.pageSize.width / 2, 10, { align: 'center' });
            }
        }
    };
    html2pdf().from(tableContent).set(opt).outputPdf('blob').then(function (pdfBlob) {
        const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
        const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        iframe.src = blobUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);

        if (confirm('Do you want to print this PDF?')) {
            iframe.onload = function () {
                iframe.contentWindow.print();
            };
        }
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event) {
            const pdfData = event.target.result;
            document.getElementById('pdfData').value = event.target.result;
            document.getElementById('pdfForm').submit();
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(pdfBlob);
    });
}

When ifframe.contentWindow.print() is executed in the above code, the callback function will not be executed. All other functions will work normally.
You can modify the code if there is a similar method to the above, even if it is not the above method. For example, you can use window.print() if the same function as above is possible by using window.print()
